# How do I change the default path of Command Prompt?

Tags: cmd, command-line

When I open up `cmd`, this is what I see:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.523]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\me>
```

How would I get it to say:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.523]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\me\Desktop\MyFolder>
```

How do I do this without using `cd Desktop\MyFile`? When I do this, it is temporary. Restart `cmd`, it still shows

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.523]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\me>
```

How do I get it to `C:\Users\me\Desktop\MyFolder>` permanently?

Comment: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/123751-change-the-default-path-in-the-command-prompt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1.` Hit the home button, and type in `cmd`.

`2.` Right-click `Command Prompt`. select, `Open in file location`.

`3.` Right-click `Command Prompt`. it should be a Shortcut.

`4.` Select the `Shortcut` tab.

`5.` In the `Start in:` text box, type in your file location. For this question it would be,

`C:\Users\me\Desktop\MyFolder`.

`6.` Hit the enter key.